# Why has my flag been declined (on a bounty question)?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged the question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588187* to a moderator as I was not able to close it since it's protected by a bounty. The moderator declined the flag with the following:

> declined - Please use standard close votes or close flags for this instead of flagging for moderators.

Which brings me two questions:

- Is this question off-topic? (To me it's about tutorial recommendation.)
- Why has my flag been declined?

Comment: What did your flag say?

Comment: @Servy it says `This is off-topic: It's a question about recommending a tutorial.`

Comment: @Thomas: Moderators cannot see that the question has a bounty on it when handling flags. You need to be *explicit* about that (and use small words). *This question is off-topic because ...., but I cannot vote to close it because there is a bounty on it. Can a moderator please remove the bounty and, optionally, close the question while there?* goes down *much* better.

Comment: @Thomas: imagine another 100 such flags in the moderator queue, all on posts that *don't* have a bounty on it, because yes, there are users that try to use the other flag to close everything they see. And there are another 2000 flags to be handled on different topics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well part of the problem was your flag which said:

> This is off-topic: It's a question about recommending a tutorial.

You shouldn't be flagging for moderator's to close questions and that's what your flag is asking. When I saw the flag, I didn't review the question in the moderator queue. I saw that flag, I declined it because we shouldn't be flagged for closing stuff.

However, if you included a note that the question has an open bounty and it is off-topic and it should be closed, then it's likely that I wouldn't have declined it. When flagging for a moderator, it's important to include all the details needed so we can correctly process the flag.

I've now refunded the bounty and closed the question as too broad.

Comment: Ok, I take note; thanks for your work! I'll be less stupid the next time :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're flagging a question because it should be closed but can't due to a bounty then it's important to *include that information in the flag text*.  You cannot *just* say that the question should be closed; it's important to say that you couldn't vote to close it because it has a bounty on it, in addition to why it should be closed.

Comment: True, *but*, that means that the moderator declined my flag *without* opening the question...

Comment: @Thomas Sure.  With that flag reason they'll virtually always auto-decline immediately.  There are way too many people just using the wrong flag type to close a question for them to investigate every single one.  If you can't use a regular vote to close, you need to explain why.  SInce you didn't, your flag was declined.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, we do that a lot. We get about 2000 flags per day on SO.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I didn't realized that!